# Read and display video from mjpeg stream in java

Tags: java, opencv, jmf, xuggle

I use the following code to broadcast live mjpeg stream from my webcam.

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamStreamer;


public class MjpegStreamingExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      Webcam w = Webcam.getDefault();
      new WebcamStreamer(8080, w, 0.5, true);
       do {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
       } while (true);
}
```

How can i receive this live stream and display it with java in another computer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code example is what you are after:

```
IpCamDevice ipcam = new B7210("B7210", "114.32.216.24");
ipcam.setAuth(new IpCamAuth("demo", "demo"));
ipcam.setSize(B7210.SIZE_QVGA);

IpCamDriver driver = new IpCamDriver();
driver.register(ipcam);

Webcam.setDriver(driver);

WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(Webcam.getDefault());
panel.setFPS(0.5); // 1 frame per 2 seconds

JFrame f = new JFrame("Night Tree Somewhere");
f.add(panel);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

So WebcamStreamer makes the stream available on some stream (port 8080 in your case) and then the below code you enter the IP address of the cam you are after.